# queue.js does not always decrement the number of active tasks

Tags: javascript, task-queue

I would like to use queue in order to execute a long list of asynchronous tasks. I tried as in the documentation (https://github.com/mbostock/queue):

```
var q = queue(1);
tasks.forEach(function(t) { q.defer(t); });
q.awaitAll(function(error, results) { console.log("all done!"); });
```

but in my case this code executes only the first task and the `awaitAll` function never runs. If I remove the queue parameter leaving simply `queue()`, meaning infinite parallelism, all the tasks are executed as expected but the `awaitAll` method does not run.
I did other tests using the following code:

```
var q = queue(2); // With or without the parallelism
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) q.defer(function (x) {$("#test" + x).text(x);}, i);
q.awaitAll(function (error, results) {alert("all done!");});
```

You can play with this code here: http://jsfiddle.net/6p9Vz/ (if you leave a number `n` for parallelism in queue call, only the content of the first `n` div will change. The alert never appear).

I opened the queue source code and the problem seems to be connected to the `callback(i)` function which is not called in all cases and thus the `active` counter is never decreased. Maybe the problem is the arguments passed to `defer()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your deferred functions need to accept a `callback` argument and call it upon completion of the task with two arguments: `error` (if any) and the result of the execution of the task.

Here's an example from the [readme](https://github.com/mbostock/queue#queuedefertask-arguments)

```
function simpleTask(callback) { // note the callback argument
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback(null, {answer: 42}); // invoking the callback to indicate task completion
  }, 250);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I already tried this solution. However, in my particular case each task starts a chain of functions, so it is very difficult to set a callback at this point, especially for the result of the execution.

Comment: Well, you need to know when a task finishes to act upon it.